# TeX rendering, curly braces, and string formatting syntax in matplotlib

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, tex

I have the following lines to render TeX annotations in my `matplotlib` plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='serif')

voltage = 220

notes = r"\noindent $V_2 = {0:.5} V$".format(voltage)

plt.annotate(notes, xy=(5,5), xytext=(7,7))
plt.show()
```

It works perfectly, but my first nitpick is that `V` is a unit of measure, therefore it should be in text mode, instead of (italicized) math mode. I try the following string:

```
notes = r"\noindent $V_2 = {0:.5} \text{V}$".format(voltage)
```

That raises an error, because `{`curly braces`}` are the ownership of Python's string formatting syntax. In the above line, only `{0:.5}` is correct; `{V}` is treated as a stranger. For example:

```
s1 = "Hello"
s2 = "World!"
print "Some string {0} {1}".format(s1, s2)
```

should give `Some string Hello World!`.

How do I make sure that TeX's `{`curly braces`}` do not interfere with Python's `{`curly braces`}`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to double the braces to be treated literally:

```
r"\noindent $V_2 = {0:.5} \text{{V}}$".format(voltage)
```

BTW, you can also write

```
\text V
```

but the best is

```
\mathrm V
```

since a unit is not really a text symbol.

Answer (score 6):

You double-curly-brace them:

```
>>> print '{{asd}} {0}'.format('foo')
{asd} foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using python formating with '{}' I prefere formating with '%', so I can avoid a bunch of braces.

So in order to render something like `3*pi/2`, I use following code

```
r'\frac{%.0f\pi}{2}' % (3)
```

instead of

```
r'\frac{{{:.0f}\pi}}{{2}}'.format(3)
```

Using it in Jupyter, the code would look like:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
display(Math(  r'\frac{%.0f\pi}{2}' % (3)  ))
```